# Getting syntax error trying to run PowerShell scripts from CloudFormation::Init

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, powershell, aws-cloudformation

I'm trying to run a PS1 script when my instance comes up and I'm getting a syntax error:

```
2018-08-01 13:15:45,951 [DEBUG] Running command 10-test
2018-08-01 13:15:45,951 [DEBUG] No test for command 10-test
2018-08-01 13:15:45,951 [ERROR] Command 10-test ('C:\ProgramData\Amazon\Scripts\install_agent.ps1') failed
2018-08-01 13:15:45,951 [DEBUG] Command 10-test output: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

2018-08-01 13:15:45,951 [ERROR] Error encountered during build of config: Command 10-test failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cfnbootstrap\construction.pyc", line 544, in run_config
  File "cfnbootstrap\construction.pyc", line 138, in run_commands
  File "cfnbootstrap\command_tool.pyc", line 117, in apply
ToolError: Command 10-test failed
2018-08-01 13:15:45,951 [ERROR] -----------------------BUILD FAILED!------------------------
2018-08-01 13:15:45,951 [ERROR] Unhandled exception during build: Command 10-test failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cfn-init", line 171, in <module>
  File "cfnbootstrap\construction.pyc", line 129, in build
  File "cfnbootstrap\construction.pyc", line 530, in build
  File "cfnbootstrap\construction.pyc", line 544, in run_config
  File "cfnbootstrap\construction.pyc", line 138, in run_commands
  File "cfnbootstrap\command_tool.pyc", line 117, in apply
ToolError: Command 10-test failed
```

Here is part of my CFN template:

```
"config": {
   "commands": {
      "10-test": {"command": "'C:\\ProgramData\\Amazon\\Scripts\\install_agent.ps1'"},
     },
     "files": {
         "C:\\ProgramData\\Amazon\\Scripts\\install_agent.ps1": {
            "source": "https://my-bucket/software/trend-micro/install_agent.ps1",
            "authentication": "S3AccessCreds"
          }
       }
   }
```

The script gets downloaded from S3 properly and if I run this same command (C:\ProgramData\Amazon\Scripts\install_agent.ps1) from a PowerShell command prompt on the Windows instance itself it works fine. I've tried quite a few different variations on the quotes (single, double, escaped) and simplified everything as much as possible, but it still doesn't work.

Can someone tell me where I'm going wrong? I'm sure it's just something simple, but I just can't figure it out. Grrrr....

Comment: Why is this tagged as Python?

Comment: Is the template supposed to be wrapping in another `{}`